# Print a whole number if the answer is whole, else print the float

Tags: python

What's the shortest, most pythonic way to print out an integer if the result of an operation is an integer, otherwise print the float? Example:

```
def calc(x, y):
    return (x / y)
```

How can I make sure that if the output of the function is a whole number, then print it as an integer, and if otherwise print it as a float? I know I can use `is_integer()` and build an `if else` statement, but is there a shorter, more pythonic way to do that?

Comment: `print(int(x) if x.is_integer() else x)`? If you don't want to write a full `if else` inside the print, you can extract it to a function called `fmt_int` or something like that.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq But is that shorter than itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
def calc(x, y):
       return (x//y if x%y== 0 else x/y)
```

I hope it's cool!  Note parentheses actually does nothing here.  Maybe readability who knows

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn’t print anything; it returns a value. That means it itself doesn’t have any control over the specifics of string formatting except by varying the type it returns. Maybe that’s what you want, a function that returns an `int` when the exact result is an integer and a `float` otherwise:

```py
def calc(x, y):
    # if x is divisible by y
    if x % y == 0:
        # integer division, producing an exact int result
        return x // y
    else:
        # floating-point division, producing an approximate float result
        return x / y
```

It’s a little weird to have variable return types, but this function could have its uses. Keep in mind that you can still get a float out of this with a zero fractional part (i.e. one that would be printed by default as “something.0”) if the fractional part is close enough to zero; `calc(10**100, 10**100-1)`, for example. There are also results too big to represent as floats that will end up producing floating-point infinity.

Or maybe instead you always want to do floating-point division, and your problem is purely one of formatting: you never want to see “.0”. That should be done separate from the calculation:

```py
# remains the same
def calc(x, y):
    return x / y


def format_without_zero(f):
    if f.is_integer():
        return str(int(f))
    else:
        return str(f)


# but you use the result differently
result = calc(10, 5)
print(format_without_zero(result))
```

Or maybe you want precise division all the time! In that case, you can create [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction)s and figure out how you want to format them.